# Alarm through socket Programming

Tags: java, swing, sockets, networking

I made digital clock in java through socket Programming.

when client send the same time of the system server match the time and play the alarm.but when client send the 1 min or 2 min greater then server not match the time with system time and not play the alarm.

here my code

**Server Side:**

```
public class GraphicsServer extends JFrame implements Runnable
{

    String wr;
    String text;
    JTextField f1;
    JTextField f2;
    JScrollPane js;
    JTextArea jt;
    JPanel p;
    Color color;
    Calendar cal;
    String time;
    String time1;
    int hrs;
    int min;
    int sec;

    public GraphicsServer()
    {
        super("Server Tik Tik Tok");
        setSize(400, 400);
        p = new JPanel();
        f1 = new JTextField(10);
        f2 = new JTextField(10);
        p.add(f1);
        p.add(f2);
        add(p);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {

            public void run()
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hrs = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    int min = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    int sec = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    String time = hrs + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
                    f2.setText(time);
                    time1 = hrs + ":" + min;
                    // System.out.println(time1);
                    // System.out.println(time);
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ee)
                    {
                        System.out.println(ee.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1111);
            while(true)
            {
                Socket ss = server.accept();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ss.getInputStream()));
                text = br.readLine();
                f1.setText(text);
                wr = time1;
                if(text.endsWith(wr))
                {
                    color = JColorChooser.showDialog(GraphicsServer.this, "Choose a color", color);
                    p.setBackground(color);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GraphicsServer gs = new GraphicsServer();
        gs.setVisible(true);
        Thread th = new Thread(gs);
        th.start();
    }
}
```

**Client Side:**

```
public class GrapClient extends JFrame
{

    JButton b1;
    JTextField f1;
    Socket client;

    public GrapClient()
    {
        super("Client Tik Tik Tok");
        setSize(400, 400);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        b1 = new JButton("Enter Alarm Time");
        f1 = new JTextField(10);
        p.add(b1);
        p.add(f1);
        add(p);
        ActionListener newListener = new ActionListener()
        {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                try
                {
                    Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 1111);
                    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
                    String g = f1.getText();
                    ps.println(g);
                    f1.setText("");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        };
        b1.addActionListener(newListener);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GrapClient GC = new GrapClient();
        GC.setVisible(true);
        GC.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

I want to make alarm clock.inside the server i embed the digital clock in textfield.when client send the alarm time to the server,server will compare the client alarm time with is digital clock time.
if the time in server side is 23:10.and client send the same time 23:10 to server the server will show the jfile chosser.
if server have the time 23:10 and client send the alarm time 23:11.when server time equal to the client alarm time after 1 min then server will open the jfilechoser.

Comment: Please revise your question: http://sscce.org/

Comment: What is your question exactly. What is happening and what did you expect to happen ?

Comment: I want to make alarm clock.inside the server i embed the digital clock in textfield.when client send the alarm time to the server,server will compare the client alarm time with is digital clock time. if the time in server side is 23:10.and client send the same time 23:10 to server the server will show the jfile chosser. if server have the time 23:10 and client send the alarm time 23:11.when server time equal to the client alarm time after 1 min then server will open the jfilechoser.

Comment: OK, now you described what you want. Now what exactly is not working, where do you get stuck, what is the part you need help for ?

Comment: ok.its working but when client send the greater time then server will not open the jfilechooser.help me what i can do in this situation when client send greater time and the server digital clock reaches and match the client alarm time and then server open the jfilechooser.see in the server code where i compare the strings

Comment: I want to make alarm clock.inside the server i embed the digital clock in textfield.when client send the alarm time to the server,server will compare the client alarm time with is digital clock time. if the time in server side is 23:10.and client send the same time 23:10 to server the server will show the jfile chosser. if server have the time 23:10 and client send the alarm time 23:11.when server time equal to the client alarm time after 1 min then server will not open the jfilechoser

Answer (score 1):

OK, there are a few problems with this code

1. You access a lot of fields from different `Thread` instances without any synchronization steps. This might result in weird threading related bugs
2. You do not access the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). It might be a good idea to read up on [Swing Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
3. Please start using decent variable names, which would make it so much easier to read your code

However, none of these points are the real issue. What the problem is is that you probably think that your (and yes, I renamed some variables)

```
  while ( true ) {
    Socket ss = server.accept();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( ss.getInputStream() ) );
    String alarmTimeFromSocket = br.readLine();
    alarmTimeTextField.setText( alarmTimeFromSocket );
    if ( alarmTimeFromSocket.endsWith( currentTime ) ) {
      color = JColorChooser.showDialog( GraphicsServer.this, "Choose a color", color );
      contentPane.setBackground( color );
    }
  }
```

runs constantly, which is not the case. The `br.readLine()` call is a blocking call. Hence that `Thread` is constantly waiting for input. Once it receives a new alarm time, it immediately executes the next piece of code (the comparison), and then starts waiting for input again.

So your comparison code is only executed the moment you set an alarm time, and not constantly when the time updates.

Besides that, I think the `endsWith` is incorrect (or you may not set a time including seconds from the client, in which case it will work but then you could easily use `equals` instead of `endsWith`)

A possible solution for your problem is to do the comparison between the alarm time and the current wall time in the loop which updates the wall time on the server side. But again, you might end with weird threading issues if another `Thread` updates the alarm time field at the same moment you compare it with the wall time in the wall-time-updater-`Thread`

Comment: i do best myself but i not reach at the solution.i am new in java.if you edit the piece of code where error occur i will be very thankfull to you..

Comment: I won't. You should try or you will never learn something new. I already indicated what the problem is (the blocking call), and explained a possible solution.

Comment: ok bro.what is blocking call and i use the threading first time.i do not know threading very well.i synchronized my all thread method but still problem there.i use the wait method but its not work.